# Image Upload Javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, image-uploading

My problem here is uploading images.. BUT I already know how to upload Base64 Images. Right now , i can upload Base64 Images and put them to databse. You can already see that is ridicolous as it will take tons of space and is hard to load. I was just checking if there is like this API Where you can upload and it gives you URL(And No I dont want Imgur, because it is banned a lot of places.) Or if there is a custom way to shorten Base64? Something that wont take as much space as Base64 Images do...

Comment: Send the plaintext, using the PUT method? Compress it using Javascript before sending? Store it in disk, instead of a database?

Comment: What @IsmaelMiguel ? PUT Method? This is Javascript. How do i compress it? Why would i store it in a disk, Im using Firebase

Comment: Decode the base64 and save the data as a blob

Comment: @Musa What? As a blob what?? I never heard this term, can you link me to a URL Or like give me code how to do this/

Comment: [HTTP PUT method](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), [Javascript ZIP compression](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=javascript+zip)

Comment: Ok i searched about Blobs... but it says not correctly encoded but it is

Comment: THANKS A LOT @Musa !!! idk if i should post anwser..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something with like TinyPNG, that compresses the photos, there is a Node.js version https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/nodejs

Alternative for non-node.js users
https://tinypng.com/developers/reference

Comment: Tinypng is a really good website.

Comment: I dont use Node.js

Comment: Then use the http api https://tinypng.com/developers/reference

Comment: Nope @jeffreycrowder i have solved this allread

Comment: The link won't be changing anytime soon my friend, it is a project and a libary widey used. Sorry, but my answer is in fact valid.